# How can an make an animation with css in Reactsjs app

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

am trying to make an animation on a button to show it from the left to right.

i have a fullscreen slider, the button is located at the top/left, it's hidden at the first item of the slider, and it is shown when we go to the next ones :
**first item :**
[image]

**The next one :**
[image]

In the first item the button(arrow) is hidden at the left side, when i go to the second item it should be shown with animation transition, it is shown but with NO animation.

Here the css code :

```
<button className="slider__btn--back"
style={{ 
    transform: `${i.id <= 1 ? "translateX(calc(-100% - 50px))" : "translateX(100%)"}`,
    transition: "all 5s 5s ease-in-out"
}}
    onClick={backTo}
>
    <img src={ leftArrow } alt="" />
</button>
```

My onClick function (to go back to the previous item):

```
 {dataSlider.map((i) => {
    const backTo = () => {
        if (currentIndex < length - 1) {
            setCurrentIndex((prevState) => prevState - 1);
        }
        if (currentIndexH1 < length - 1) {
            setCurrentIndexH1((prevState) => prevState - 1);
        }
   
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIdLoader((idLoader) => idLoader - 1);
        }, 1900);layCarouselState(true);
        }, 2700);
    };
 })}
```

The button css :

```
.slider__btn--back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 999;  
  // transition: transform .5s 5s ease-in-out;
  // transform: translateX(calc(-100% - 50px));
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just added another condition in the ternary  :

```
`<button className="slider__btn--back"
                    style={{ 
                        transform: `${i.id > 1 && displayCarouselState ? "translateY(100%)" : "translateY(calc(-100% - 50px))"}`,
                        transition: "all .4s linear"
                    }}
                        onClick={backTo}
                    >
                        <img src={ leftArrow } alt="" />
                    </button>
```